# React Apollo Error: Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, next.js

I'm building a project using React, Apollo and Next.js. I'm trying to update react-apollo to 3.1.3 and I'm now getting the following error when viewing the site.

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

If I downgrade the react-apollo package to 2.5.8 it works without issue so I'm thinking something has changed between 2.5 and 3.x but can't find anything in the react-apollo or next-with-apollo documentation to indicate what that might be. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

withData.js

```
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { endpoint } from '../config';

function createClient({ headers }) {
    return new ApolloClient({
        uri: endpoint,
        request: operation => {
            operation.setContext({
                fetchOptions: {
                    credentials: 'include'
                },
                headers
            });
        },
        // local data
        clientState: {
            resolvers: {
                Mutation: {}
            },
            defaults: {}
        }
    });
}

export default withApollo(createClient);
```

_app.js

```
import App from 'next/app';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import Page from '../components/Page';
import { Overlay } from '../components/styles/Overlay';
import withData from '../lib/withData';

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {};
        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }

        // this exposes the query to the user
        pageProps.query = ctx.query;
        return { pageProps };
    }

    render() {
        const { Component, apollo, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
                <Overlay id="page-overlay" />
                <Page>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Page>
            </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default withData(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In my case, I found that I had `react-apollo@3.0.1` installed as well as `@apollo/react-hooks@3.0.0`. Removing `@apollo/react-hooks` and just relying on `react-apollo` fixed the invariant issue for me. Make sure that you aren't using any mismatched versions in your lock file or `package.json`

This is what someone said in a GitHub issue thread, which, was the case for me too. Make sure you try it!

Comment: Then there's also `react-apollo-hooks` vs `@apollo/react-hooks` — you want the latter, watch out!

Comment: Similar case for me- I had been importing ApolloProvider from react-apollo but importing useQuery from @apollo/react-hooks. Importing ApolloProvider from @apollo/react-hooks fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @DannyRosenblatt that was the case for me as well, I think most of the tutorials online follow the approach of importing the ApolloProvider from 'react-apollo' instead of @apollo/react-hooks.

Comment: The documentation for apollo v2 is terrible - if you wanna use react components, instead of hooks, you'll need to manually install @apollo/react-components and import everything from there instead. It doesn't say that anywhere, had to figure it out hard way.

Answer (score 12):

I've had a mixture of solutions, i think it does boil down to how you initially go about setting up all the related packages.

> "Some packages don't work well with others when it comes to connecting the client to Reacts `Context.Provider`"

I've had two go two fixes that seem to work well (With new projects and updating old):

1: Uninstall `@apollo/react-hooks`

Then:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
```

instead of:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
```

(This allowed me to keep the "@apollo/react-hooks" package without conflicts)

3: Double-check that the server that is serving `HttpLink` client `URI` is up and running for the client to connect (This give a different error then the one were talking about but is still good to know in this situation)

**Conclusion:** It can be a slight bit of trial and error, but try to use the matching/pairing packages

Answer (score 5):

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {graphql} from '@apollo/react-hoc';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
```

These imports worked for me perfectly. I had a great time debugging and finding different import libraries but finally after 3 hours this was the solution for using graphql and appolo.

Answer (score 4):

I uninstalled 'react-apollo', used '@apollo/client' instead, it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the solution as well, though now I'm only using `@apollo/client` and `apollo-link` since they are the latest version.

Comment: You found what to be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

import {ApolloProvider} from 'apollo/client' instead 'react-apollo'or '@apollo/react-hooks'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue and the following fixed the issue for me:

```
 "resolutions": {
    "@apollo/react-common": "3.1.3",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "3.1.3",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
this will solve the problem in next js .
also import useQueries or useMutation from '@apollo/client'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).