# How do I solve the "Could not find "client" in the context..." issue for Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Error message:

> Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an `<ApolloProvider>`, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

`useQuery(LINK_QUERY)` is returning the error above. I've tried using switching `useQuery` to `<Query> ... </Query>`, and it didn't solve the issue. I've also tried refactoring the `index.js` file and using `ApolloHooksProvider` mentioned [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2042). The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475780/react-apollo-error-invariant-violation-could-not-find-client-in-the-context) has not solved the issue either.

Code block:

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import LINK_QUERY from "../graphql/queries/GetAllLinks";

function MakeSlug(length) {
  let slug = "";
  let characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  let charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    slug += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return CheckSlug(slug);
}

function CheckSlug(slug) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LINK_QUERY);

  if (loading) return "Loading";
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return data.allLinks.map((link) => {
    if (link.slug === slug) {
      return MakeSlug(4);
    } else {
      return slug;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = MakeSlug;
```

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-liskov-tkhtm?file=/src/services/MakeSlug.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code base and changed all `apollo-boost` and `react-apollo` dependencies to `@apollo/client`.

This required a little refactoring. It wasn't that wild of a change.

`<Query>` changed to `useQuery`. And `<Mutation>` changed to `useMutation`. Personally, I prefer the `<Query>` and `<Mutation>` ways of writing the codebase but it appears to be a more consistent way to write the code to use one dependency than more than one.