# ReactJS apolloClient Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am not getting why it is firing me this problem, and it was worked same way before in my another application. I just tried last 3 days, i coulndt figure out this issue yet.

I found this solution on stackoverflow: [React Apollo Error: Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475780/react-apollo-error-invariant-violation-could-not-find-client-in-the-context)

But it is not solved my problem

Can anyone help me in this case?

THis is my App.js

```
import EmpTable from './components/empTable';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';


import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});




function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <EmpTable />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my EmplyeeTable

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";


function EmpTable() {

  const GET_EMPLOYEE = gql`
    query getEmp($id: String) {
      employeeById(id: $id) {
        id
        name
        role
      }
    }
  `;


  const {refetch} = useQuery(GET_EMPLOYEE)

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {/* some div  */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmpTable;
```

I am getting following error with this code:

```
Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.
new InvariantError
src/invariant.ts:12
   9 | export class InvariantError extends Error {
  10 |   framesToPop = 1;
  11 |   name = genericMessage;
> 12 |   constructor(message: string | number = genericMessage) {
  13 |     super(
  14 |       typeof message === "number"
  15 |         ? `${genericMessage}: ${message} (see https://github.com/apollographql/invariant-packages)`
View compiled
invariant
src/invariant.ts:27
  24 |   message?: string | number,
  25 | ): asserts condition {
  26 |   if (!condition) {
> 27 |     throw new InvariantError(message);
  28 |   }
  29 | }
  30 |
```

The error is too long i just puted few of them here. Can anyone please let me know what exactly the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `ApolloProvider` from `@apollo/client`

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
```